# How can i get two input field values based on onclick function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a div in that div I have two input fields and update button like this:

```
<button type = "button" id = "add-botton" >Add Element </button>
    <div id = "trace-div1" class = "trace">
    <h4><span>Trace 1</span></h4>
    <form>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>X Axis:  </label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="t_x_axis" class = "t_x_axis"  id="x_axis_t1" size="50"> 
                    </td>                                               
               </tr>                                                                            
               <tr>
                    <td><label>Y Axis:  </label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="t_y_axis" class = "t_y_axis" id="y_axis_t1" size="50"></td>
                    <td><button type = "button" name = "update-button-trace" class = "update-trace" id = 
                         "update-botton-trace1" onclick="updatebtn(this)">Update </button></td>
                </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
       </form>                              
    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#add-botton').click(function(){
              var $div = $('div[id^="trace-div"]:last');
              var num = parseInt( $div.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10 ) +1;
              var $trace1div = $div.clone(true).prop('id', 'trace-div'+num );
               $trace1div.find('span').text('Trace ' + num);
               $trace1div.find("input[name='t_x_axis']").attr("id", "x_axis_t"+num).val("");
               $trace1div.find("input[name='t_y_axis']").attr("id", "y_axis_t"+num).val("");
               $trace1div.find("button[name='update-button-trace']").attr("id", "update-button - 
             trace"+num);
              $div.after( $trace1div);


                });
        });
    function updatebtn(el){
            var id = $(el).attr('id');
    }
    }
</script>
```

Here I am cloning my div multiple times with diff.id's ,my problem is when I click update button i need those respective two input values. 
I tried like this but here I am getting all input value like if I have add 3 divs those respective all values coming here each div has 2 input fields :

```
<script>
 function updatebtn(el){
       var id = $(el).attr('id');
       $('input[type=text]:visible').each(function(){
                 console.log($(this).val());
        })
})
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DOM traversal to find the `input` elements related to the button which was clicked. The simplest way to do that, given that you're already using jQuery, would be to use a delegated event handler for the dynamic `button` elements along with `closest()` and `find()`.

It's also worth noting that your use of `id` attributes within the dynamic content is creating a *lot* more problems than it solves. I'd strongly suggest you remove them all and use common classes on all elements. That way you don't have the headache of having to manually update all the incremental ids when adding new content.

Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var $traceContainer = $('#traces');

  $('#add-button').click(function() {
    var $div = $traceContainer.find('.trace:last').clone()
    $div.find("input[name='t_x_axis']").val("");
    $div.find("input[name='t_y_axis']").val("");
    $traceContainer.append($div);
    $div.find('span').text('Trace ' + ($div.index() + 1));
  });
  
  $traceContainer.on('click', '.update-trace', function() {
    var $container = $(this).closest('table');
    var xAxis = $container.find('input[name="t_x_axis"]').val();
    var yAxis = $container.find('input[name="t_y_axis"]').val();
    
    console.log(xAxis, yAxis);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="add-button">Add Element</button>
<div id="traces">
  <div class="trace">
    <h4><span>Trace 1</span></h4>
    <form>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><label>X Axis:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="t_x_axis" class="t_x_axis" size="50">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><label>Y Axis:</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="t_y_axis" class="t_y_axis" size="50"></td>
            <td><button type="button" name="update-button-trace" class="update-trace">Update </button></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Finally, note that I added a `div` container around each `.trace` to make appending them and retrieving their index simpler. Also note that the `form` within each `.trace` seems redundant and can probably be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use find value as `$div.find('.t_y_axis').val()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#add-botton').click(function(){
             
              var $div = $('div[id^="trace-div"]:last');
              var num = parseInt( $div.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10 ) +1;
              var $trace1div = $div.clone(true).prop('id', 'trace-div'+num );
              
              
               $trace1div.find('span').text('Trace ' + num);
               $trace1div.find("input[name='t_x_axis']").attr("id", "x_axis_t"+num).val("");
               $trace1div.find("input[name='t_y_axis']").attr("id", "y_axis_t"+num).val("");
               $trace1div.find("button[name='update-button-trace']").attr("id", "update-button-trace"+num);
              $div.after( $trace1div);
              
              console.log( 'last t_y_axis => ' , $div.find('.t_y_axis').val());
              console.log( 'last t_x_axis => ' , $div.find('.t_x_axis').val());

        });
   });
    
    function updatebtn(el){
            var id = $(el).attr('id');
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type = "button" id = "add-botton" >Add Element </button>
    <div id = "trace-div1" class = "trace">
    <h4><span>Trace 1</span></h4>
    <form>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>X Axis:  </label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="t_x_axis" class = "t_x_axis"  id="x_axis_t1" size="50"> 
                    </td>                                               
               </tr>                                                                            
               <tr>
                    <td><label>Y Axis:  </label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="t_y_axis" class = "t_y_axis" id="y_axis_t1" size="50"></td>
                    <td><button type = "button" name = "update-button-trace" class = "update-trace" id = 
                         "update-botton-trace1" onclick="updatebtn(this)">Update </button></td>
                </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
       </form>                              
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the following function.since both the input text boxes have their id you can use the same to get the value of the inputs.
Hope it helps!

```
function updatebtn(el) {
      var x1 = document.getElementById('x_axis_t1');      
      var y1 = document.getElementById('y_axis_t1');

      alert('x-axis is ',x1.value, ' and y-axis is', y1.value)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to develop your updatebtn().

```
 function updatebtn(el){
        var element = $(el),
            parent_table = element.parentsUntil('table');
        x_axis = parent_table.find('.t_x_axis').val();
        y_axis = parent_table.find('.t_y_axis').val(); 
}
```